# How can I add custom input event receiver in wso2cep 4.0.0?

Tags: java, wso2-cep

I'm trying to create a custom input event receiver based on wso2cep 4.0.0 documentation and the decompiled version of filetail input event receiver from cep/repository/components/plugins.(https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/Building+Custom+Event+Receivers).

So far I've managed to add all the classes from the decompiled version, and build a project based on that. After I've copied it in cep_home/repository/components/dropins, I tried to launch CEP server and then I've encountered this:

```
[2015-12-04 14:00:31,483] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.multiplefiletail.internal.ds.MultipleFileTailEventAdapterServiceDS} -  Cannot create the MultipleFile input event adapter service!
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.multiplefiletail.i18n.Resources, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:795)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.multiplefiletail.MultipleFileTailEventAdapterFactory.<init>(MultipleFileTailEventAdapterFactory.java:20)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.multiplefiletail.internal.ds.MultipleFileTailEventAdapterServiceDS.activate(MultipleFileTailEventAdapterServiceDS.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:517)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:91)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)}
```

The error emerges at line: `private ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.multiplefiletail.i18n.Resources", Locale.getDefault());`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.core.InputEventAdapter;
import org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.core.InputEventAdapterConfiguration;
import org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.core.InputEventAdapterFactory;
import org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.core.Property;

public class MultipleFileTailEventAdapterFactory
extends InputEventAdapterFactory
{
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MultipleFileTailEventAdapterFactory.class);
    private ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.multiplefiletail.i18n.Resources", Locale.getDefault());

    public String getType()
    {
        return "multiplefile-tail";
    }

    public List<String> getSupportedMessageFormats()
    {
        List<String> supportInputMessageTypes = new ArrayList();
        supportInputMessageTypes.add("text");
        return supportInputMessageTypes;
    }

    public List<Property> getPropertyList()
    {
        List<Property> propertyList = new ArrayList();

        log.info("Method call:MultipleFileEventReceiver::getInputMessageProperties()");

        Property filePath = new Property("filepath");
        filePath.setDisplayName(this.resourceBundle.getString("filepath"));
        filePath.setRequired(true);
        filePath.setHint(this.resourceBundle.getString("filepathHint"));
        propertyList.add(filePath);

        Property filePattern = new Property("filepattern");
        filePattern.setDisplayName(this.resourceBundle.getString("filepattern"));
        filePattern.setRequired(true);
        filePattern.setHint(this.resourceBundle.getString("filepatternHint"));
        propertyList.add(filePattern);

        Property procFolder = new Property("procfolder");
        procFolder.setDisplayName(this.resourceBundle.getString("procfolder"));
        procFolder.setRequired(true);
        procFolder.setHint(this.resourceBundle.getString("procfolderHint"));
        propertyList.add(procFolder);

        Property streamDefinitionProperty = new Property("separator");
        streamDefinitionProperty.setDisplayName("separator");
        streamDefinitionProperty.setRequired(true);
        streamDefinitionProperty.setHint(this.resourceBundle.getString("separatorHint"));
        propertyList.add(streamDefinitionProperty);

        Property numberFields = new Property("numberFields");
        numberFields.setDisplayName(this.resourceBundle.getString("numberFields"));
        numberFields.setRequired(true);
        numberFields.setHint(this.resourceBundle.getString("numberFieldsHint"));
        propertyList.add(numberFields);

        return propertyList;
    }

    public String getUsageTips()
    {
        return this.resourceBundle.getString("file.usage.tips");
    }

    public InputEventAdapter createEventAdapter(InputEventAdapterConfiguration eventAdapterConfiguration, Map<String, String> globalProperties)
    {
        return new MultipleFileTailEventAdapter(eventAdapterConfiguration, globalProperties);
    }
```

I don't understand why in the original compiled adapter that class is the same and it works and in my case it doesn't.

Can anybody help me?? Thank you very much!

(If you need any other information about this problem, tell me in comments, thanks)

Comment: Is Resources.properties file there, under resources, as in https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics-common/blob/master/components/event-receiver/event-input-adapters/org.wso2.carbon.event.input.adapter.filetail/src/main/resources/org/wso2/carbon/event/input/adapter/filetail/i18n/Resources.properties ?

Comment: Hi, beside the comments with copyright, licensed to apache etc. It is almost the same I modifid some things to suit my adapter, tomorrow I can add it if you wish. Thanks

Comment: so, this is my Resources.properties: `filepath=Source Files Folder
filepathHint=This is the folder containing event files
filepattern=File Pattern
filepatternHint=This is the pattern of the files to be processed
procfolder=Processed Files Folder
procfolderHint=This is the folder where processed event files are moved to
separator=Field Separator
separatorHint=This is the field separator in the respective file
numberFields=Number of Fields
numberFieldsHint=Number of Fields in the respective file` which is located in the same place like in the link you've provided.

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake, the resources folder doesn't match with the path from ServiceDS, now it's working..thanks.

Comment: Hi, Glad that you got it to work :)

Comment: ...and can I suggest you to add your finding as an answer since that resolved your issue..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research and thanks to Dilini (Thank you!) I've managed to find that the error appeared because I incorrectly configured the Resources folder, it was

`src/main/resources/org/wso2/event/adapter/multiplefiletail/i18n/Resources`

instead of

`src/main/resources/org/wso2/carbon/event/input/adapter/multiplefiletail/i18n/Resources`

like it was configured in MultipleFileTailEventAdapterFactory class, where the error emerged. Hope it helps!